# Magento 2 - Update collection data through ajax

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

I have a collection inside my Block file `Vendor\MyModule\Block\PostsCollectionList.php`

```
protected function postCollection()
{
    return $this->postCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addActiveFilter()
        ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
        ->setOrder($this->getCollectionOrderField(), $this->getCollectionOrderDirection());
}
```

Then I have declared my phtml file in layout XML file -

```
<block class="Vendor\MyModule\Block\PostsCollectionList" name="posts.list" template="postsCollectionList.phtml" />
```

There I have this collection and I have also created some filters and once I select filter I update my URL and pass the selected filter to Controller through Ajax but at this point I am stuck. How can I get and update my collection through the controller based on the selected filter and update then frontend?

For example, I want to pass the filter `country=spain` as my selected filter to controller and then retrieve filtered collection which where declared inside my Block file but with additional filter country.

I know that there should be an `execute()` method but not exactly sure what I have to do to get collection which was before created in my Block file so I could apply additional country filter to my collection and then update frontend accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the big picture is:
your ajax request should send the filter attribute code and its value (attribute option id or attribute label) within the post data

```
$("#click_me").on('click', function (e) {
            var self = this;
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: config.ajaxUrl,
                data: {
                    filter_data: JSON.stringnify({.... many data might be there}),
                    form_key: $.cookie('form_key')
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,

                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('body').trigger('processStart');
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log('success', res.message);

                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                }
            });
        });
```

then, in your controller, you would pick this data using request like below:

```
/**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $resultRedirect->setRefererUrl();
        }

        $filterData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filter_data');
```

// here you would rebuild your block using layout

$html = .....

```
        $result = [
            'success' => true,
            'html' => $html
        ];

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    }
```